Комп перестал уходить в сон (Windows)
Некоторое время назад комп перестал уходить в сон с отключением питания. Нажимаю заветную кнопку — отключается только монитор, всё остальное работает. При этом гибернация работает. Началось это после перезагрузки, а что стало причиной понять сложно, т.к. с момента прошлой перезагрузки и обновления ставились, и новые проги...
Методом перебора вариантов выяснилось, что комп начинает нормально засыпать при отключении службы "Питание" (C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k DcomLaunch -p).
При отключенной службе и попытке зайти в раздел "Электропитание" панели управления появляется сообщение "Сервер RPC недоступен", и выбора схемы питания нет. Соответственно, экран никогда не гаснет, процессор всегда работает на максимальной частоте.
В общем, дичь какая-то! Как можно это починить?
P.S. sfc /scannow и Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth запускал, ничего не меняется.
P.P.S. Win 11 Pro x64

попробуйте нажимать на кнопку выключения примерно 5-10 секунд (Неважно ПК это или ноутбук).

Если не поможет пиши, я отвечу в свободное время.

Вы имеете в виду просто зажать и держать 5 секунд? Компьютер выключится.

да это так работает

Как это поможет решить мою проблему? :)

Любой комп при нажатии на кнопку выключения примерно 5-10 сек выключается физически а не программно. А поэтому проблем не должно быть.

Так, в этом и не было проблемы. Проблема в том, чтобы отправить комп в сон с автоматическим отключением питания. Вы читали вопрос?

Понял, возможно проблема в BIOS .Тогда нужно обновить BIOS вашего ноутбука. От какой компании ваш ноутбук?

Это не ноутбук, стац. комп. Изменений в BIOS не было, я проверил. Обновить могу, конечно. Но если всё работает при отключенной службе "Питание", полагаю BIOS тут ни при чём.

Бывает что из-за старой версии прошивки биос ос перестает нормально работать. Но можете попробовать переустановить виндовс
